# Laurent series for functions with branch singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

I'm trying to derive a form of the [indentation lemma](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/Complex_Methods/rjs/indentation.pdf) for a function of the form, say, $f(z)=\frac{h(z)}{\sqrt{z^2-k^2_0}}$, where $h(z)$ is analytic, and $k_0$ is some possibly complex number. As such, I was wondering if it were possible to express this series in terms of a Laurent series? As I am not very clear on this topic, it seems that expanding the denominator in a Taylor series gives a set of terms with fractional powers, and use of Cauchy's integral formula does not seem possible due to the branch cut. As such, I was wondering how to proceed.

Comment: Laurent series by definition are for holomorphic functions with isolated singularities.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(z^2-k^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{i k (1-z^2/k^2)^{1/2}}$ is analytic on $|z| < |k|$ thus so is $f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{(z^2-k^2)^{1/2}}$, where is your trouble ? The alternate expansion is the Laurent series of $f(1/z)$ on $|z| < 1/|k|$ using the Laurent series of $h(1/z)$ and that $(1/z^2-k^2)^{1/2} = z^{-1} (1-k^2 z^2)^{1/2}$.